# How to configure a stage in azure pipeline for getting an email notification after a deployment is success?

Tags: azure-devops, deployment, devops, pipeline, cicd

I want a template where it send an email notification after the deployment to certain environment is success.

i tried but unable to get it

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: i tried setting it up in notification in project settings but i want a template where we can configure it in yaml

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add a PowerShell task to run scripts calling the REST API to send mail after the successful stage.

Below PS script for your reference, if you are running it in pipeline, then please use the `$(System.AccessToken)` instead of `$PAT`.

Running locally and authenticate with `PAT`:

```
$OrganizationName = "organization"
$ProjectName = "Project"
$sendmailto = "xxx@microsoft.com"
$mysubject = "Test Mail Subjcet"
$PAT="xxx"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT"))

$HeaderMail = @{
    Authorization = "Basic $encodedCreds"
}

#Get the tfsid

$userentitlementurl = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/${OrganizationName}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $userentitlementurl -Method Get -Headers $HeaderMail

#Filter by sendmailto
$tfsid = ($response.value| where {$_.user.mailAddress -eq $sendmailto}).id

Write-Host $tfsid

##send mail
$urimail = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/${OrganizationName}/${ProjectName}/_apis/Release/sendmail/168?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
$requestBody =
@"
{
    "senderType": 1,
    "to": {
        "tfsIds": [
            "$tfsid"
        ],
        "emailAddresses": []
    },
    "subject": "$mysubject",
    "sections": [
        5,
        0,
        1,
        2,
        4
    ]
}
"@
Try {
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urimail -Body $requestBody -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $HeaderMail
}
Catch {
$_.Exception
}
```

[image]

Running in release pipeline and authenticate with `$(System.AccessToken)`: (Please note that, because this script is being run during the release, the summary email will show the environment as `IN PROGRESS` even if it is run as the last step in the Release.)

```
$OrganizationName = "organization"
$ProjectName = "project"
$sendmailto = "xxx@microsoft.com"
$mysubject = "Test Mail Subjcet"

$HeaderMail = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
 
#Get the tfsid

$userentitlementurl = "https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/${OrganizationName}/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $userentitlementurl -Method Get -Headers $HeaderMail

#Filter by sendmailto
$tfsid = ($response.value| where {$_.user.mailAddress -eq $sendmailto}).id

Write-Host $tfsid

##send mail
$urimail = "$env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT/_apis/Release/sendmail/$($env:RELEASE_RELEASEID)?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$requestBody =
@"
{
    "senderType": 1,
    "to": {
        "tfsIds": [
            "$tfsid"
        ],
        "emailAddresses": []
    },
    "subject": "$mysubject",
    "sections": [
        5,
        0,
        1,
        2,
        4
    ]
}
"@
Try {
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urimail -Body $requestBody -Method POST -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $HeaderMail
}
Catch {
$_.Exception
}
```

[image]

Reference this blog for details:  [Send simple email in Azure DevOps using PowerShell (without any smtp server)](https://medium.com/globant/send-simple-email-in-azure-devops-using-powershell-without-any-smtp-server-bd669a24e544)

Comment: is there any job or stage which i can add in the yaml?

Comment: You can add job or stage based on your requirement, just add PowerShell task to run the script calling the REST API to send mail notification.